# Automatic url alias creation for posts

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to be able to convert the title of blog posts to auto-generated URLs in django like this:

- title: This is Article #1  => blog/article-1
- title: Cooking spaghetti and meatballs => blog/cooking-spaghetti-meatballs
- title: #%#@$! h4h4h4 spam 5@#$! => blog/h4h4h4-spam

they should be autogenerated and filtered for excess words/characters as they are created. Each time you save the blog post, if you change the title, the URL may change as well.

I could definitely program this from scratch. However, in Drupal for example, there already was a module called 'url alias' and 'autopath' that generated these urls as soon as you submit your new blog post. I'm wondering if someone already built something simple for Django 1.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#slugfield), and pair it with the title field using Django's [prepopulated fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) functionality.

Comment: Ok I can do that in the admin, but do I just use slugify in the process of my adding-an-article function and save a SlugField for the model of my content-type?

Comment: @Dexter: You can use `django.template.defaultfilters.slugify` in view code to create slugs, or use the [`SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#slugfield) in a custom form.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
slugify("b b b b")
u'b-b-b-b'
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you. Then I just have to add my filters of certain words/characters.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty nice, simple module called [Django Autoslug](http://packages.python.org/django-autoslug/) that I've been using that builds on top of the SlugField mentioned by mipadi, but it automatically creates the slug for you, checks the database for uniqueness (by default, adding '-#' to the end of the slug until it's unique), and stores it to a field.

Comment: This is nice, but there are no steps listed here to install this and how to get it to work.